# Unable to execute python file using command prompt. Gives error "No SSL Support included in this python"

Tags: python, ssl, smtp, starttls

I have .py file that simply sends an email with excel attachment. 
From visual studio code it executes and delivers the file with no problem.

But when I execute this file with using command prompt it gives me an error: "No SSL Support included in this python".

Command Prompt opened as Administrator.

So what can be the reason that it works from Visual Studio Code but does not work with Command Prompt

[image]

This is what I see if I type python in command prompt:

[image]

**Also, it works if I use terminal from Visual Studio Code. I can see that "base" environment is activated. So is it something to do with it?**

[image]

```
fromaddr = "from@email"
toaddr = "To@email" 
# instance of MIMEMultipart 
msg = MIMEMultipart() 
# storing the senders email address   
msg['From'] = fromaddr 
# storing the receivers email address  
msg['To'] = toaddr  
# storing the subject  
msg['Subject'] = "Sending Attachement"
# string to store the body of the mail 
body = "Hello, This is Test and my attached file" 
# attach the body with the msg instance 
msg.attach(MIMEText(body, 'plain')) 
# open the file to be sent  
filename = "ExpirationList.xlsx"
attachment = open('C:\\Users\\Folder\\ExpirationList.xlsx',mode = 'rb') #rb opens file in bytes mode, not in text mode 
# instance of MIMEBase and named as p 
p = MIMEBase('application', 'octet-stream') 
# To change the payload into encoded form 
p.set_payload((attachment).read())  
# encode into base64 
encoders.encode_base64(p) 

p.add_header('Content-Disposition', "attachment; filename= %s" % filename) 

# attach the instance 'p' to instance 'msg' 
msg.attach(p) 

# creates SMTP session 
s = smtplib.SMTP('1.1.1.1: 25') 

# start TLS for security 
s.starttls() 

# Authentication 
#s.login(fromaddr, "Password") 

# Converts the Multipart msg into a string 
text = msg.as_string() 

# sending the mail 
s.sendmail(fromaddr, toaddr, text) 

# terminating the session 
s.quit()
```

Comment: Is it possible your Command Prompt and VS Code Studio are using the different versions of Python?

Comment: Possible. How would I check for that? Thanks

Comment: You can check on VS Code by opening the [command palette](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/tips-and-tricks#_command-palette) and entering _Python: Select Interpreter_. You should see the current one as a placeholder

Comment: Thanks. So I needed to activate base environment in command prompt. Then it worked.